# how to access a variable that's inside a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to do 4 steps where I ask the user for a "key character" and a string, then capitalize the string, then remove all instances of the key character from the string. Each of these steps is supposed to be its own function. However, steps 3 and 4 rely on accessing variables located in the functions from steps 1 and 2.

I've read a few threads on this such as the following...
[How to access the variables declared inside functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931491/how-to-access-the-variables-declared-inside-functions-in-python)
...which suggests you must "return" the variables after defining them, but I've done that (I think) and it hasn't changed anything.

```
def main():
    get_key_character()
    get_string()
    sentence_capitalizer()
    remove_key_character()

def get_key_character():
    key_character=str(input("Please enter a SINGLE character to act as key? "))
    if len(key_character)!=1:
        get_key_character()
    else:
        return key_character

def get_string():
    phrase_input=str(input("Please enter a phrase or sentence >=4 and <=500 characters: "))
    if len(phrase_input) <4 or len(phrase_input)>500:
        get_string()
    else:
        return phrase_input

def sentence_capitalizer():
    import re
    sentence_capitalized=(re.sub(r"(^|\?|\.|\!)\s*(\w)", lambda q: q[0].upper(), phrase_input))
    return sentence_capitalized 

def remove_key_character():
    sentence_capitalized.replace(key_character, "")


main()
```

error: undefined name phrase_input in def sentence_capitalizer and undefined name key_character in def remove_key_character

Comment: You need to assign the returned value in a variable and pass it to the next function in each case

Comment: Take some time to learn about parameters and returning a value from a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is that the returned value must be stored in another variable.
For example,

```py
def test():
    x = 1
    return x

def main():
    z = test()
    print(z)

main()
```

This program will output:

```
1
```

You must pass the output of your functions as *parameters* to the subsequent calls of different functions. I have reworked your code to work like this.

```py
def main():
    key_character = get_key_character()
    phrase_input = get_string()
    sentence_capitalized = sentence_capitalizer(phrase_input)
    removed = remove_key_character(key_character, sentence_capitalized)
    print(removed)

def get_key_character():
    key_character=""
    while len(key_character) < 1:
        key_character=str(input("Please enter a SINGLE character to act as key? "))

    return key_character

def get_string():
    phrase_input=str(input("Please enter a phrase or sentence >=4 and <=500 characters: "))
    if len(phrase_input) <4 or len(phrase_input)>500:
        get_string()
    else:
        return phrase_input

def sentence_capitalizer(phrase_input):
    import re
    sentence_capitalized=(re.sub(r"(^|\?|\.|\!)\s*(\w)", lambda q: q[0].upper(), phrase_input))
    return sentence_capitalized 

def remove_key_character(key_character, sentence_capitalized):
    return sentence_capitalized.replace(key_character, "")


main()
```

Comment: `input` returns a `str` by definition in Python 3, so there is no need to do `str(input(...))`. You are still not returning anything in the recursive call.

Comment: I know. I just copied his code vertbatim. Thanks for the note about the recursive call though! Didn't catch that. @tripleee

Comment: Thank you for that reply. Now I'm receiving the following error, I suppose because, as tripleee pointed out, the way I have my functions set up, they return "None."

-----------------------------------------------------------------

  File "C:/Users/Jaimen/.spyder-py3/practice7.py", line 34, in remove_key_character
    return sentence_capitalized.replace(key_character, "")

TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not None

Comment: Further on in the traceback you should see which function called `replace_key_character` with the `key_character` argument set to `None`.

Comment: I modified my sample code. You can try it again, but I don't think the original should be broken either (if you are running my copy)

Comment: Ok. It seems like something is wrong with my copy of Spyder. Anyway thanks for the replies, I understand the general concept which you outlined in your initial paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

> if len(key_character)!=1:
>      get_key_character()

Your function does not `return` anything (so implicitly returns `None`) in this case. You want to `return get_key_character()` (or perhaps more usefully refactor to avoid recursion, i.e. add a `while` loop and exit it when you receive a valid character, rather than have the function call itself until it receives a valid character).

More generally, you should avoid global variables. Every time a function returns something useful, the *calling* code should assign that value to a *local* variable. If you need to pass that value to another function, make that function accept a parameter into another *local* variable of its own.

Comment: Idk if it's acceptable to post links here. I tried replying with code and couldn't get the formatting to work at all. https://i.imgur.com/by1dnDH.png

Comment: Images of code are vehemently hated, for good reasons (see e.g. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode for a rationale). If you want to link to code, post it on a code hosting site like https://ideone.com/ or https://repl.it/ or at least a text hosting site like https://pastebin.com/ ... And maybe explain why we should click through - are you having a problem still, or are you just looking for a review or further feedback?

Comment: Ok thank you for the info. I read the page on comment formatting which suggested indenting text by 4 spaces or using control-K, but neither of those worked for me....could you clarify whether this site supports commenting w/code? Otherwise in the future I can use the code hosting sites you mentioned. 

And to explain, I modified the applicable sections of code as per your feedback (writing a while loop instead of having the function call itself) so I was just wondering if I was on the right track but (that section of) the code seems to work so I guess I don't need further validation..

Comment: Indeed, there is no support for code formatting in comments.